# Error mining has not been started :possibly lost conection to daemon

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I watch monero cli easy video on youtube by GingerAle.I did everythig like this video except that I used monero-wallet-cli.exe --daemon-host (moneroworld random nodes ip):18089 --trusted-daemon.I think it works properly and syncing completed .But just like in video   (Error mining has not been started :possibly lost conection to daemon ),
I get this message .Although monerowallet.cli.exe finished syncing ,monerod is continued syncing eg .- - - - -/- - - - - -that consume much data.I don't know am i mining or not yet .
what should I do ,pls?Btw I just a beginner .

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are trying to start mining on a random remote node.

When you connect your wallet to a remote node and enter the *start_mining* command, you are in fact asking the remote Monero daemon to start solo mining and sending the reward to your address if it finds a block. Obviously, the owner of the remote node will not allow random stranger's wallets to use his computing power (by starting his Monero daemon with the *--restricted-rpc* option).

The *start_mining* command will only work if your wallet is connected (with the *--trusted-daemon* option) to one of your own Monero daemons (i.e. started without the *--restricted-rpc* option, and not openly accessible from the whole internet).

Comment: glv , your reply opens my knowledge ,it's great .To get a daemon full node by myself is so hard because my country internet charge is expensive ,and it'll take too long .What should I do ?pls to continue to mine monero.Do I need to run full nodes?I've mined in minergate software 2 weeks ago .It's very easy but it cost me so much bandwidth ,abt 200MB/hr.So I try this .
with regards

Comment: Reading more threads ,I come to know that remote nodes are used for transaction , checking balance and other ,not for start mining .Right? I may be wrong .

Comment: If you want to mine without having your own node, you will have to use a mining pool. The pools usually have a page with info on what mining software you can use (for example https://monero.crypto-pool.fr/#getting_started).